# How do I remove congealed, hardened filament from around the hot end from a Cubicon Single Plus

Tags: filament

I have a Cubicon Single Plus printer, and the filament has balled up all around the nozzle and hot end. I was wondering if there is any easier way than butting it off carefully with a pair of side cutters.

I have heated up the block and nozzle to 230 degrees Celsius, but that may not help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the right tool for this, a brass brush, something like:

[image: brass brush sample]

They're typically available for less than a dollar from hardware stores, or you can order them various places online.

Use it while the nozzle is hot, and with the sock removed, and everything should come right off. Take care not to brush the electrical connections to the heater/thermistor, since this might cause a short and fry your controller board if any conductors are inadvertently exposed.